# Set a default radio input and corresponding checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a react material UI group input field thats mapping a data set. The output is one radio button and one checkbox doing the same thing. Firstly, I have tried setting the state to set one data item as default. I have copied the example on the [react-ui site](https://material-ui.com/demos/selection-controls/) but cant see what the difference is in [my example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xp9rpw1ro4).

Also, the checkbox must also follow suit of the select radio button and vice versa.

```
class RadioButtonsGroup extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 1
  };

  handlePersonToggle = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label="matches"
        name="matches"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handlePersonToggle}
      >
        {data.map(person => (
          <div>
            <FormControlLabel
              value={person.Id}
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
            />
            <FormControlLabel value={person.Id} control={<Checkbox />} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </RadioGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

Codesandbox example - https://codesandbox.io/s/xp9rpw1ro4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues here:

1. The immediate child of RadioGroup needs to be an array of e.g. FormControlLabels
2. You need to either cast the value of the Radio to string or the value in the state to number. Input values are always strings and RadioGroup relies on strict equality check.

Solution:

```
<RadioGroup
  aria-label="matches"
  name="matches"
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.handlePersonToggle}
>
  {data.map(person => (
    <FormControlLabel key={person.Id}
      value={String(person.Id)}
      control={<Radio color="primary" />}
    />
  ))}
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

**your JSON:**

```
  {
        Id: 4,
        profilePicture: "http://via.placeholder.com/150x150",
        firstName: "Mike",
        lastName: "Rudge",
        cat: "old",
        checked:true,
      }
```

**your render:**

```
 <FormControlLabel
              value={person.Id}
              checked={person.checked}
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
            />
```

*You need pass prop  checked={true}*

Comment: Yes that defaults them however I dont have the option to create a checked value in my data set. Also, this then keeps the default value default regardless on which radio button is selected next